# Does Salt provide a mechanism for retrieving data as the master and providing that data to minions?

Tags: salt-stack

The problem / use case:
In order for Salt to apply the correct states to minions, Salt needs to be aware of the role a given minion is intended to fill.

We define this through tags on Azure VMs and custom attributes on vSphere VMs.

In order to minimize auth concerns, we want the salt master to be responsible for retrieving this data and providing it to minions.

Does Salt provide these capabilities? What are they?

Answer (score 1):

ext_pillar is how a master connects to azura and vsphere to collect data about minions and then send that data to minions. since this is pillar data it is also target-able in almost everything as pillar data. the one exception being pillar.

- https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/development/modules/external_pillars.html
- https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/pillar/all/salt.pillar.azureblob.html#module-salt.pillar.azureblob
- https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/pillar/all/salt.pillar.vmware_pillar.html#module-salt.pillar.vmware_pillar

Comment: You had me covered on reddit but I appreciate the reply here as well. Thanks!